# .NET framework source stepping not working despite options set

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have these options enabled, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I also have the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` module selected:

[image: screenshot]

Yet it steps over the code. Specifically, I have this code in a subclass of `ListBox`:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

I tried to set a breakpoint there and then step into this with F11, but it just steps over.

What is missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They didn't release the source code for the latest patch for .NET 4.0 that comes with VS2010 SP1 so if you have that installed, it won't be able to find the right source files thus not be able to display it. That's the exact behavior with me also. Rolling back the update solves the problem but then I don't get to use the goodies that come with SP1.

If you select the option to print diagnostic messages, you'll get the warning that sources cannot be found at the server. You can download the RTM source from referencesource.microsoft.com and manually browse the sources otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is an bug registered on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/697947/net-framework-4-reference-sources-fail-since-out-of-date) for this if you want to upvote it.